# How can I configure KDevelop to build before executing?

Tags: c++, kdevelop

In most IDEs (e.g. Visual Studio, all the java IDEs, etc) by default the sources are build when the user selects to execute or debug the application. How can I configure KDevelop to do the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the Run->Launch Configurations menu item.

There you can configure a launch configuration, with arguments, working directory, etc.

At the bottom, there is a dependencies block, where you can specify a build target that should be run before the execution of the launch configuration.

Comment: What should I put as the build target? I have a CMake project, but when I selected the main CMakeList.txt file, the system complained.

Comment: Ok. Your CMakeLists.txt should declare several targets, usually in the target_link_libraries step. These targets should come up in the launch configuration.